# HTML tags replacing with php

Tags: php, html, tags

If I have a paragraph:

```
echo "^b(This sentence becomes bold), and ^i(this becomes italic).\nThen this becomes ^up(uppercase).";
```

how to replace ^b, ^i, ^up, \n into a HTML tags ?

> **This sentence becomes bold**, and *this becomes italic*.
>
> Then this becomes UPPERCASE.

Thankyou.

Comment: We're here to help you sort out issues with your existing code. However, we're not here to do your job for you.
Post what you've tried, example data, expected result and what you're currently getting. You can read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more info.

Comment: Is this some kind of framework? I've never seen coding like that.

Comment: As mentioned previously, we're not here to do your homework. I would advice you looking to formal grammars, it's a good way to address these kind of problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use preg_replace() with patterns to do this:

```
<?php

// your example text
$text = "^b(This sentence becomes bold), and ^i(this becomes italic).\nThen this becomes ^up(uppercase).";

// array of patterns
$patterns = [];
$patterns[0] = "/\^b\((.*?)\)/";
$patterns[1] = "/\^i\((.*?)\)/";
$patterns[2] = "/\^up\((.*?)\)/";

// array of replacements    
$replacements = [];
$replacements[0] = '<b>${1}</b>';
$replacements[1] = '<i>${1}</i>';
$replacements[2] = '<span style="text-transform:uppercase;">${1}</span>'; // or use something better here

// process the text
$formattedText = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $text); 

// see the result
echo $formattedText;

?>
```

It would be much better if you write this logic in a helper function so you could use it easier on different places later.